# Configuring log4j in Liferay tomcat server for displaying logs in jsp

Tags: jsp, tomcat, liferay-6

I created a jsp to analyze the server logs..it was deployed as a portlet. Now i want the jsp to be in root folder.

*I have two options* :-

1] either I user ext-plugin approach which i want to avoid\

2] Just place the *jsp* in root folder.

If i go with the second approach where should i place the log4j.properties and custom appender file so that I can see the logs in jsp which is in the root folder*(....\webapps\ROOT).*
My property file is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,logfile,console,SystemStatus
log4j.logger=INFO,logfile,console,SystemStatus

# Console appender (stdout)
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%p] <%t> [%X{jsessionId}] [%c] %m%n

# File appender
log4j.appender.logfile=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.File=${catalina.base}/logs/copofi.log
log4j.appender.logfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [%p] <%t> [%X{jsessionId}] [%c] %m%n

log4j.appender.SystemStatus=org.copofi.common.logging.SystemStatusAppender
```